# UnityTest not calling Update() function on MonoBehaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've a simple Unity unit test which checks my CameraController MonoBehaviour moves position after a frame update:

```
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator AfterOneFrame_CameraMovesRight()
    {
        var cameraController = new GameObject().AddComponent<CameraController>();

        yield return null;

        Assert.That(cameraController.transform.position.x, Is.EqualTo(5));
    }
```

But this fails, the CameraController instance is created but the Update() function never gets executed.

According to the documentation, `yield return null;` should be causing this to happen?

When I run my scene the camera scrolls to the right (5 at a time), so the CameraController's Update() function is correct, it's just not being called during the test.

*(this is an EditMode test)*

Comment: It should be a PlayMode test if you want to test how `Update` calls affect things.

[See this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53883846/1092820)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity: What's the difference between a PlayMode UnityTest and an EditMode UnityTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877088/unity-whats-the-difference-between-a-playmode-unitytest-and-an-editmode-unityt)