# PlayMode Tests with Coroutine SetUp

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit

I'm new in testing for Unity3D, and I wanted to write some tests for our game. I managed to write this tests which work **fine**:

```
using System.Collections;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;
using Game.Characters;
using Game.Inventory;

namespace Tests
{
    public class ItemTests
    {
        [UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator ItemIsOnHand()
        {
            // Setup
            Player player = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Tests/Player"));
            yield return null; // Wait for prefab to load
            Character character = player.GetComponent<Character>();
            WorldItem worldItem = WorldItem.Create(Resources.Load<Item>("Items/item"), 1);
            yield return null; // Wait for prefab to load
            character.Inventory.Give(worldItem);
            ItemScript itemScript = character.HandItemContainer.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<ItemScript>();

            // Test
            Assert.IsNotNull(itemScript);

            // Teardown
            Object.Destroy(player);
            Object.Destroy(character);
            Object.Destroy(worldItem);
            Object.Destroy(itemScript);
        }

        [UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator ItemIsDisabledAtStart()
        {
            // Setup
            Player player = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Tests/Player"));
            yield return null; // Wait for prefab to load
            Character character = player.GetComponent<Character>();
            WorldItem worldItem = WorldItem.Create(Resources.Load<Item>("Items/item"), 1);
            yield return null; // Wait for prefab to load
            character.Inventory.Give(worldItem);
            ItemScript itemScript = character.HandItemContainer.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<ItemScript>();

            // Test
            Assert.IsFalse(itemScript.IsActive);

            // Teardown
            Object.Destroy(player);
            Object.Destroy(character);
            Object.Destroy(worldItem);
            Object.Destroy(itemScript); 
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both tests (and other tests too) use the same setup and teardown. I declare the variables outside the methods (to be available for every test). Teardown method is working fine, as it doesn't need to wait for anything to load.

```
        private Player player;
        private Character character;
        private WorldItem worldItem;
        private ItemScript itemScript;

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            Debug.Log("Teardown called");
            Object.Destroy(player);
            Object.Destroy(character);
            Object.Destroy(ectomodulatorWorldItem);
        }
```

But I can't manage to make the SetUp method work. If I make it a coroutine (`[SetUp] public IEnumerator SetUp(){...}`) it never runs (I checked with the debugger). And if I make it a simple void method and delete the `yield return null`s, it fails at `character.Inventory.Give(worldItem);` because `worldItem` is still `null`.

Is there a way I can make a SetUp method work?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than `yield return null` have you tried `yield return new WaitWhile (() -> player == null)`? Also, you you using the pseudo-runtime tests?

Comment: @Draco18s `yield return null` works fine, but I can try the `WaitWhile` way.

I don't know what pseudo-runtime tests are, sorry. I'm using NUnit.Framework and running tests in PlayMode.

Comment: *`and running tests in PlayMode`* That's what I meant by "pseudo-runtime." Normally unit tests are done outside play mode, but Unity has certain features that require playmode to work.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm not sure what's the difference between both, and which one I need.  
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877088/unity-whats-the-difference-between-a-playmode-unitytest-and-an-editmode-unityt) says that PlayMode is needed to test physics, and I'll be testing Collider2D detections, that's why I thought PlayMode would be appropiate

Comment: You're absolutely correct to use it in this case. Its just that there's a non-playmode test path as well, and its faster, but you don't have much access to almost anything in the UnityEngine package (which is why I asked if you were using the playmode path, because if you weren't, you'd need to).

Comment: as a side note, unity3d does not guarantee to call `OnTriggerEnter(Collider)` and `OnTriggerExit(Collider)` correctly if you have collisions in rapid succession. You can easily end up with less *exits* than *enters*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I needed. Just like `[Test]` attribute only works on `void` methods and you need to use `[UnityTest]` to run a coroutine, there is also a `[UnitySetUp]` attribute that allows to use coroutine setup instead of a `void` one.

Link to the docs for more info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@1.1/manual/reference-actions-outside-tests.html#unitysetup-and-unityteardown

In case you're interested, my tests file is like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;
using Game.Characters;
using Game.Inventory;

namespace Tests
{
    public class ItemTests
    {
        Player player;
        Character character;
        WorldItem worldItem;
        ItemScript itemScript;

        [UnitySetUp]
        public IEnumerator SetUp()
        {
            player = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Tests/Player"));
            yield return null; // Wait for prefab to load
            character = player.GetComponent<Character>();
            worldItem = WorldItem.Create(Resources.Load<Item>("Items/item"), 1);
            yield return null; // Wait for prefab to load
            character.Inventory.Give(worldItem);
            itemScript = character.HandItemContainer.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<ItemScript>();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            Object.Destroy(player);
            Object.Destroy(character);
            Object.Destroy(ectomodulatorWorldItem);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ItemIsOnHand()
        {
            // Test
            Assert.IsNotNull(itemScript);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ItemIsDisabledAtStart()
        {
            // Test
            Assert.IsFalse(itemScript.IsActive);
        }
    }
}
```